# AWS Centos SSH Port not responding

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, centos

I have a couple AWS instances running CentOS. Every few days the SSH ports stop connecting on both instances. When I try to SSH into the server it just keeps trying to connect and doesn't timeout. Hence I am not able to login into the server at all. The apache service works fine and website is served with no issues.

The Cron Jobs also stops working when the SSH port is down.

The only solution is to restart the instance. After restart it will run fine for a few days and SSH stops again after few days.

I have spoken to AWS support and they could not find anything. The logs also don't show anything and the logs stop logging after the issue starts.

Need help where to start troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: Does SSH tunnel from Session Manager work?

Comment: Session Manager and Serial Console both dont work

Comment: Just some recommendations, you can install cloudwatch agent or third party service to track instance memory in case of memory leak. Or you can track CPU usage and CPU credit if you are using burst-able instance.